# Pyinstaller executable fails with pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound error

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm making a PDF Tool executable using tkinter. Anyways, the executable was successfully created by pyinstaller, but it won't run. I flagged --onedir and added the necessary dependency files --add-data. I also added the paths to my non standard library packages using --paths flag. When I run the executable from the command prompt, I get this:
[image]

The problem appears to come from the ocrmypdf module and says pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound. I tried searching for the fix, but all the problems I saw were a bit different from my issue because the .py script runs just fine for me. Is this a pyinstaller issue, or am I missing a module? I'm using pyinstaller 4.0 as well.

Comment: This issue has been asked here twice already and there has not been a solution yet. Hopefully youll be the first person to get the answer.

Comment: As this appears ocrmypdf-specific, did you try asking for help on the ocrmypdf github issues?

Comment: I'll put it in github,but the stack overflow community rules. @barny

Comment: Ask on the pyinstaller github issues too. The developers of these brilliant packeges are best-placed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After researching a little bit more, I've found the solution. The problem lies with pyinstaller, not the ocrmypdf module. The solution is that you have to create hook py scripts within a folder in your project. It's a little bit different depending on which module you use, but for this case, I had to create two hook py scripts within a folder that I called 'hooks'. These are the two scripts I made:

**hook-ocrmypdf.py**

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all('ocrmypdf')
```

**hook-pikepdf.py**

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all('pikepdf')
```

For more information go [here.](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1713)

Additionally, you must add the --additional-hooks-dir *HookFolderPath* flag to the pyinstaller command.

Comment: This has worked for me. A small note: a hook file name should contain an import name as it gets imported, it should not! be named after a Pip package. Example: `hook-yaml.py` has worked, `hook-PyYAML.py` has not.

Comment: Another gotcha: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/8003#issuecomment-1760270530.